# Parsing sitecore webform model to javascript file

Tags: javascript, json, webforms, sitecore, ascx

I am trying to parse a sitecore webform to a javascript file. In doing so I have tried to use the `Newtonsoft.Json` .Net package to convert the object to a json object which can be used by javascript

This prints the object as expected

```
<script>
    console.log("hello", <%=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model) %>);
</script>
```

However I need to use the object inside the referenced javascript file, so I've tried to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..."
    data-questions="<%=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model) %>"
    ></script>
```

In the javascript file I have then referenced the model by doing

```
var jsScript = $('#id-off-script');
var dataQuestions = jsScript.attr('data-questions');
```

&

```
var dataQuestions = document.currentScript.getAttribute('data-questions');
```

But all the above solutions comes out as

> [{

Why is the object not read properly inside the javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the `window` property. Before the injected script from a source, I insert the data into the `window`.

```
<script>
    window.data = {};
    window.data.model = <%=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model) %>;
</script>
```

& then read it from the javascript file like this:

```
console.log("model", window.data.model);
```

If anyone know a better method for using a kind of parameters I am open for that.

Comment: It was highly likely, that because your JSON contained double quotes (") it was causing the attribute value to end sooner than you imagined. imagine:  `<script data-questions="[{"aKey": "aValue"}]"`. As soon as that first " is hit, the data attribute ends.